# What is the fastest way to add data to a list without duplication in python (2.5)

Tags: python, list

I have about half a million items that need to be placed in a list, I can't have duplications, and if an item is already there I need to get it's index. So far I have

```
if Item in List:
    ItemNumber=List.index(Item)
else:
    List.append(Item)
    ItemNumber=List.index(Item)
```

The problem is that as the list grows it gets progressively slower until at some point it just isn't worth doing.  I am limited to python 2.5 because it is an embedded system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) (in CPython since version 2.4) to efficiently look up duplicate values. If you really need an indexed system as well, you can use both a set and list.

Doing your lookups using a set will remove the overhead of `if Item in List`, but not that of `List.index(Item)`

Please note `ItemNumber=List.index(Item)` will be very inefficient to do after `List.append(Item)`. You know the length of the list, so your index can be retrieved with `ItemNumber = len(List)-1`.

To completely remove the overhead of `List.index` (because that method will search through the list - very inefficient on larger sets), you can use a dict mapping Items back to their index.

I might rewrite it as follows:

```
# earlier in the program, NOT inside the loop
Dup = {}

# inside your loop to add items:
if Item in Dup:
    ItemNumber = Dup[Item]
else:
    List.append(Item)
    Dup[Item] = ItemNumber = len(List)-1
```

Answer (score 16):

If you really need to keep the data in an array, I'd use a separate dictionary to keep track of duplicates. This requires twice as much memory, but won't slow down significantly.

```
existing = dict()
if Item in existing:
    ItemNumber = existing[Item]
else:
    ItemNumber = existing[Item] = len(List)
    List.append(Item)
```

However, if you don't need to save the order of items you should just use a `set` instead. This will take almost as little space as a list, yet will be as fast as a dictionary.

```
Items = set()
# ...
Items.add(Item) # will do nothing if Item is already added
```

Both of these require that your object is *hashable*. In Python, most types are hashable unless they are a container whose contents can be modified. For example: `list`s are not hashable because you can modify their contents, but `tuple`s are hashable because you cannot.

If you were trying to store values that aren't hashable, there isn't a fast general solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can improve the check a lot:

```
check = set(List)

for Item in NewList:
    if Item in check: ItemNumber = List.index(Item)
    else:
        ItemNumber = len(List)
        List.append(Item)
```

Or, even better, if order is not important you can do this:

```
oldlist = set(List)
addlist = set(AddList)
newlist = list(oldlist | addlist)
```

And if you need to loop over the items that were duplicated:

```
for item in (oldlist & addlist):
    pass # do stuff
```